# Python: File not found in module directory

Tags: python

I've made a python module with some functions:

This is one of my modules, where "object" should be an image, like "1.png".

module/find.py:

```
def find(object):
    obj = cv2.imread(object, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    ...
```

I've placed this module inside my venv's lib folder and imported it in my project using `from module.find import find`.

However, when I'm trying to pass the object, being a picture in my project's folder, it doesn't work. But if I place that same picture inside the module's folder (venv/lib/module), it works.

How can I make my module use a picture passed from a project's folder?

Comment: Pass the full, absolute, path. You can use `pathlib.Path` to help out, with the `resolve()` method. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Have you tried passing the full path to the image?  Sounds like your module is only searching the local directory for the image.

Comment: Passing full path works. But is there a way to make the module grab the image from the project's folder directly, as if function were in the project's folder?

Comment: Additionally, seriously consider renaming your variable from ‘object’ as this is overwriting the built-in type.  Also, look into how to package Python modules/libraries for install (a wheel for example) rather than just copying your module into lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the image’s **full path** into your function.

Currently, your module is only searching its local directory.

#### Additional Question:

“Is there a way to make the module grab the image from the project's folder directly, as if function were in the project's folder?”

And retain the module’s generalised (best-practice) functionality? No.

However, if you de-generalise the module, you can hard code the path to the image in the function itself, and use the ‘os.path.join()’ function to create the full path, using the passed image name.  Albeit; this approach is discouraged due to hard coding in a (would-be) general function; thus making it useless to any image in a different directory.

#### Suggestion:

Bite the bullet and keep a **general** function which can be used for other projects later; and just pass the explicit path.

Comment: Passing full path works. But is there a way to make the module grab the image from the project's folder directly, as if function were in the project's folder?

Comment: @ankh - Edited.  Not the answer you’re looking for; but considers best practices.

Comment: Sure. I'm just new to programing.

Comment: Understood, we’ve all been there!  Please consider these suggestions, as noted above:  Additionally, seriously consider renaming your variable from ‘object’ as this is overwriting the built-in type. Also, look into how to package Python modules/libraries for install (a wheel for example) rather than just copying your module into lib.